# catalog_product index does not exist yet. Make sure everything is reindexed

Tags: magento2.3, category-products, reindex, elasticsearch, cronjobs

In our production site using Magento 2.3.4 and Smile-SA elasticsuite extension with elasticsuite 6.x. After manual reindex site working well. But some time shows an error.

> main.CRITICAL: catalog_product index does not exist yet. Make sure
> everything is reindexed.
> {"report_id":"f338fd2af9106c0ec4b09c83855f9a3ca4424092acd1f25958036944b2915173","exception":"[object]
> (LogicException(code: 0): catalog_product index does not exist yet.
> Make sure everything is reindexed. at
> /var/www/html/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-core/Index/IndexOperation.php:117)"}
> []

Then show nothing in category page and admin panel category edit panel. But after manual reindex, it works again normally. But after some time again show that error. What happens their or how to resolve it.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue did you find any solution.

Answer (score 7):

Please check https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/318#issuecomment-435322698, that fixed it for me. As this is a bit old, the command should be :
`bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsuite --lock-env && bin/magento cache:flush && bin/magento index:reindex`